# Quotient of UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$, it is known that

> $I$ is prime $\iff$ $R/I$ is an integral domain.

**Question:**

If we assume that $R$ is a **UFD** with $1$, is it true that

> $I$ is prime $\iff$ $R/I$ is a UFD?

what if UFD is replaced by PID?

**Update**
For the last part, I mean:

> If $R$ is PID, then
>
> $I$ is prime $\iff$ $R/I$ is PID?

Comment: In the last question, do you mean "when R is a PID"?

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403565/when-a-quotient-of-a-ufd-is-also-a-ufd , you'll see that a quotient of a UFD is not always a IFD even when it is integral.

Comment: And, no, in general if $R$ is a UFD and $I$ is prime, it is not necessarily the case that $R/I$ is a PID. For example, $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ is a UFD, $(y)$ is a prime ideal, but $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(y) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a PID.

Comment: @lhf Yes. That is what I mean

Comment: (Ehr... where are you “replacing” UFD by PID? In the premise, or in the “if and only if” statement?)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin See updates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First question is hard; see for example [this prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403565/when-a-quotient-of-a-ufd-is-also-a-ufd). In general, it is difficult to know if a quotient of a UFD is a factorial ring (every element can be written as a product of a unit and irreducible elements, though perhaps not uniquely), let alone a unique factorization ring.

Second question is, alas, trivial. If $R$ is a principal ideal **ring**, then *any* quotient of $R$ is a principal ideal ring: if $I\triangleleft R$, and $K$ is an ideal of $R/I$, then $K=J/I$ for some (unique) ideal $J$ of $R$ that contains $I$. Since $R$ is a PIR, $J=(a)$ for some $a\in R$. Every element of $K$ is of the form $j+I$ for some $j\in J$, and hence $j$ is of the form $na + ra + as + \sum_{i=1}^m(r_ias_i) + I$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $m\geq 0$, $r,s,r_i,s_i\in R$ (not assuming $R$ is commutative or has a $1$). But 
$$na+ra+as+\sum_{i=1}^m(r_ias_i)+I$$
is the same as
$$n(a+I) + (r+I)(a+I)+(a+I)(s+I) + \sum_{i=1}^m((r_i+I)(a+I)(s_i+I)),$$
which is clearly in the principal ideal $(a+I)$ of $R/I$; hence $K\subseteq (a+I)$. And since $a\in J$, trivially $(a+I)\subseteq K$, giving equality. Thus, $K=(a+I)$ is principal.

In particular, for a principal ideal commutative ring with unity $R$, $I$ is prime if and only if $R/I$ is a PID; since “principal ideal” holds just because $R$ is a principal ideal ring, and then this equivalent is all about whether it is a domain or not.